# Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Socket closed)>

Tags: python, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

- tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0
- tensorflow-server 1.10.0

I have deployed a tensorflow server which serves several models.
The client code is like `client.py` this and I call the predict function.

```
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, port)
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()

def predict(data, shape, model_name, signature_name="predict"):
    request.model_spec.name = model_name
    request.model_spec.signature_name = signature_name
    request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=shape))
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
    return result.outputs['prediction'].float_val[0]
```

I have about 100 clients with the same configuration.
And here is a sample code to call the `predict` function:

```
from client import predict
while True:
    print(predict(data, shape, model_name))
    # time.sleep some while
```

At first, when I run the client code, I can receieve the reponse **correctly**.
But after several hours, the client crashed with the error

```
_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Socket closed)
```

I have try to modify my client code to

```
def predict(data, shape, model_name, signature_name="predict"):
    channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, port)
    stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = model_name
    request.model_spec.signature_name = signature_name
    request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=shape))
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
    return result.outputs['prediction'].float_val[0]
```

that means I try to establish the connection with the tfs server each time the `predict` function is called. But this code also failed just like before.

So what should I do to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I added a `channel.close()` before `return` and it works fine.